# ActionListener doesn't call action in 'Bean View' when there is already a record in the database (Primefaces + Hibernate + JPA)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I have an error, which may be simple, but I'm not able to resolve it.

I have a simple registration screen, where everything works fine, and I've a p:selectOneMenu that brings me a list of customers to choose from (Convert works fine).

However, when I try to save a record that the selected customer already has in my base, it doesn't save and it doesn't give an error, neither on console, it just leave p:selectOneMenu with a red border, my method isn't even called on my bean view.

Main Class:

```
@Entity
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
public class EmailGds implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public EmailGds() {
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "emails_gds_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "emails_gds_seq", sequenceName = "emailsgds_id_seq",     allocationSize = 1)
@Column
private Long id;

@IdentificaCampoPesquisa(descricaoCampo = "Cliente do Projeto", campoConsulta = "c_id", principal = 1)
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "c_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "none", value =     ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT), nullable = false, unique = true)
private v_clientesgds c_id; //This guy is my field with problem
...
//Getters and setters
```

My p:selectOneMenu:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="conteinerCliente" value="#{emailGdsMB.selectedEmailGds.c_id}" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" rendered="#{emailGdsMB.selectedEmailGds.novo}" >
                        <f:selectItems value="#{emailGdsMB.lstClientesGds}" var="objClients" itemValue="#{objClients}" itemLabel="#{objClients.fantasy_name}" />
                        <p:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{emailGdsMB.analisaSelecao}" process="@form"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Save button:

```
<p:commandButton id="bt_save" title="Salvar" icon="pi pi-save" actionListener="#{emailGdsMB.save}" update="manage-content" partialSubmit="false" process="@this,@form" immediate="false" />
```

Save Function:

```
public void save() {
   System.out.println("Salvando Registro");
   try {
       if (validarCampoObrigatorio(this.selectedEmailGds)) {
           if (this.selectedEmailGds.getId() == null) {
               selectedEmailGds.setStore_id(selectedEmailGds.getC_id().getStore_id());
               selectedEmailGds.setUser_create(userSessao);
               emailGdsDao.save(selectedEmailGds);
               this.emailGdss = emailGdsDao.loadLista();
               this.selectedEmailGds = new EmailGds();
               FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Email acesso ao GDS Adicionado"));
           } else {
               selectedEmailGds.setStore_id(selectedEmailGds.getC_id().getStore_id());
               selectedEmailGds.setUser_update(userSessao);
               emailGdsDao.save(selectedEmailGds);
               this.emailGdss = emailGdsDao.loadLista();
               this.selectedEmailGds = new EmailGds();
               FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Email acesso ao GDS Atualizado"));
           }
           PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("formEmailGds:messages", "formEmailGds:dtable");
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.err.println("Erro ao salvar EmailGDS "+e);
   }
}
```

In short, when I select a customer that has never been saved, it performs all, including the event 'valueChange' ajax. But if I select a client that has already been saved (on database table), it doesn't execute anything, neither the save method nor the AJAX 'valueChange' event.

My converter is working fine

If I put in the save button: ajax="false", it returns the message:

> Validation error: value is not valid

My environment:

Jsf 2.2
Hibernate
Primefaces 8
Spring boot
Postgres

PS: Update data works fine.

EDIT 1:

v_clientesgds is a view in my database.

My Converter:

```java
@FacesConverter(forClass = v_clientesgds.class)
public class v_clientesgdsConverter implements Converter {
    private static Session session =     HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String codigo) {
        if (codigo != null && !codigo.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Converter getAsObject: " + codigo);
            v_clientesgds ret = session.get(v_clientesgds.class, new Long(codigo));
            System.out.println("Customer name converter: " + ret.getFantasy_name());
            return ret;
        }
        System.out.println("FIM Executando converter getAsObject: " + codigo);
        return codigo;
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object objeto) {
        if (objeto != null) {
            v_clientesgds c = (v_clientesgds) objeto;
            return c.getC_id() != null && c.getC_id() > 0 ? c.getC_id().toString() : null;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't post your converter code.  But could the issue be because the new records don't have an ID yet and your converter is counting on an ID.  Also if you get the Red Border put a p:messages on your screen and update that from the button so you can see the actual error message

Comment: I edited and typed now the converter code, when i put p:message, i received the error: 'Validation error: value is not valid '. Thanks @Melloware

Comment: OK yeah value is not valid something in your code is messed up. Its saying the value of the SelectOne is not a valid value and not even sending it to your converter.

Comment: But I'm receiving object from converter, for all request, just when i'll save a new record (that has been saved before) I get error. I put an output on the console and I can see it's returning the right object.

Comment: Make sure the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods of your POJO are implemented properly.  It could be your new object it can't tell apart from an existing object.